# How to use HTML 5 geo location in android WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, geolocation

I am working on a project that needs to get user's current location using HTML 5 geolocation. But I need to know why `WebView` is not showing my current location. 
What I've to do to show the map and current location in `WebView`??

I just want to view http://html5demos.com/geo in my `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is using http as opposed to https; browsers (and embedded WebView components) are switching to allowing HTML5 geolocation only on secure origins:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

You should try confirm that Android WebView has upgraded to require https for HTML5 geo.

Answer (score 0):

> If you’re writing an Android app that uses a WebView to display Web content, you must specifically enable geolocation in the WebView in order for pages that use it to work properly.

- [Enable Geolocation in a WebView (Android) « TurboManage](https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/how-to-enable-geolocation-in-a-webview-android/)

At china,the api can't connect to google services and then maybe can't get it work! so you can implement youself JavaScript bridge api to get a location.

source of inspiration: [Browser_compatibility Geolocation API - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Please explain in your own words, don't just copy-paste from some external source alone.